# Server port returns null

Tags: c#

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]
```

&

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"]
```

return `null` when called via webservice code.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Context.Request.ServerVariables[]` in your WebService code.

**Edit**
According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.context.aspx):

> XML Web service methods that have
>   either the SoapRpcMethodAttribute or
>   SoapDocumentMethodAttribute attribute
>   applied to them with the OneWay
>   property of set to true, do not have
>   access to their HttpContext using the
>   static Current property. To access the
>   HttpContext, derive the class
>   implementing the XML Web service
>   method from WebService and access the
>   Context property.

Does this apply to you?

Comment: That doesn't help, btw "HttpContext.Current" returns null.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 - Oh, you should be more clear about that in your question. I have added some more info I found on it to my Answer. See above.